# How to select the real MAX integer in a char column?

Tags: mysql, asterisk

The queue_log table in Asterisk record some calls data.

All the columns are char(50) because sometimes the save String data and sometimes save integer data.

I have a query to get some info about calls.
In this query I always get integer data in a column, and I want to get the MAX.

MySQL return me an incoherent MAX data.

How can I get the real MAX value of a char column getting in all rows Integer data?

Answer (score 4):

Yuck!  But this data format is sometimes necessary, especially when you have entity-attribute-value (EAV) data structures.  Even in that case, it is advisable to have different columns for different types, so this type of operation is more natural.

But, you can actually do what you want easily in MySQL.  If the integers are always non-negative, the following should easily work:

```
select max(col + 0)
from queue_log ql;
```

MySQL will convert the string to a number for the addition.  It silently ignores letters.  And, the conversion stops at the first letter.  If there are no digits at the beginning of the string, it will return 0.

Note:  this will also convert decimal numbers as well.  You specify "integer" but you are not clear if there are decimal numbers that you want to ignore.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`CAST()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) function,

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(COLUMN as INTEGER)) FROM TABLE;
```